# How to extract separated punctuation characters and symbols in PHP string correctly?

Tags: php

I have a string in PHP where I want to extract separated punctuation characters and symbols where in MS Office are detected as a word, this is an example:

```
<?php 

$string='La edad de un personaje, ¿ha de escribirse con letras o con 
cifras? ¿ Y las fechas y las horas ? ¿ Y los ordinales ? no llevan un 
punto o una coma , separando los millares ( 25.957 o 1.859 ) . Los 
números de cuatro cifras NO llevarán separación (1859): y los números 
de cinco cifras o más NO llevarán : ni puntos ni comas, 
sino una separación ( 25 957 o 1 343 392 ) .';

?>
```

In this case, I try to extract those characters with this lines:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/[[:punct:]\d]+/', $string, $matches);
$characters = implode(" ",$matches[0]);
$characters = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $characters);
```

But the problem is I obtain all the characters, including those are not separated, and some of them are omitted:

```
, ? ? ? , ( . . ) . ( ) : : , ( ) .
```

And I want to get this result:

```
¿ ? ¿ ? , ( ) . : ( ) .
```

How can I fix it?

I'd like your help.

Comment: Can you check your wanted result, or explain how to get it?

Comment: `[:punct:]` does not include `¿` so you need to add it to the character set manually or use the unicode modifier `/u`. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html for more information.

Comment: What is the purpose of `\d`? You do not mention anything about getting numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're matching all punctuation without specifying that there must be whitespace surrounding it. Add this restriction to your regular expression as follows:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=( [[:punct:]\d]+ ))/u', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I see this symbol `¿`is being omitted, How can I include it in the expression?

Comment: @NekoLopez Ah, right. You're running into problems because those are unicode characters. You'll need to enable unicode mode for this. Please see the updated answer. Also, please note that when you log the result, you'll see the unicode representation of the punctuation mark, not the mark itself.

Comment: There 3 unicode characters '¿' and it's showing me only one.

Comment: You'll only expect 2 out of the 3 given the restraints you've specified. That being said, one of the two is missing. This is because if two matches would overlap, then only the first will show up. This occurs at the matches `" ? "` and `" ¿ "` because they share the same space character between them. I've updated my answer to help handle these cases. If you run into any further problems, those will likely be beyond the scope of your original question. In such an event, please ask a new question encapsulating the new problems, rather than amending the existing resolved question.